# Как лучше написать регистрацию на PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Написал код регистрации. Но я не уверен, что он правильный, хотя он и работает. Что мне стоит учесть при последующем использовании этого кода?

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$username'");
$res1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = '$email'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$count1 = mysqli_num_rows($res1);

if( $count > 0) {
  $badlog = "К сожалению этот логин уже используется, попробуйте другой.";
  require '/templates/reg.php';
} elseif ($count1 > 0) {
  $badmail = 'К сожалению этот E-mail уже используется, попробуйте другой.';
  require '/templates/reg.php';
} else {
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `user`(`id`, `surname`, `name`, `email`, `username`, `password`) 
        VALUES ('','$surname','$name', '$email','$username',md5('$password'))");
    echo "Регистрация прошла успешно, теперь вы можете авторизоваться";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78359/discussion-on-question-by--------p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая главная ошибка в вашем коде, это то, что вы совершенно не позаботились о безопасности. При работе с пользовательским вводом и базой данных, первая мысль которая должна прийти вам в голову - это защита от SQL и XSS атак.

Что касается защиты от SQL тут всё просто: любые запросы к БД где существует пользовательский ввод мы осуществляем ТОЛЬКО через подготовленные выражения. Поэтому, обязательно ознакомьтесь с [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). Вот еще [отличное описание](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo) работы с PDO.

Что касается XSS атак - из вашего фрагмента кода непонятно, как будут использоваться далее отправленные методом POST данные. Но я бы, как минимум позаботился о том, чтобы ограничить в этих данных использование html тегов, функциями  [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) или [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php).

Ну и валидность email'a не мешало бы проверить с помощью [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php)